# Using threading in pyQt5, push task to the front of the queue

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I have a user interface in which big files are being imported. This can take a while, so the importing of files is done in a (or several) worker threads. However, as the files are being imported, the user should be able to look at them as they are being imported (i.e. some data from the files are plotted to the UI using matplotlib).

If the plotting operation is not done in a separate thread, it does not run until the importing of files is almost complete. But if it is done in the worker thread, the operation is just put onto the end of the queue.

So, I'm looking for a way to push the new operation to the front of the queue, or (even better) run the operation in the GUI thread simultaneous with the importing files in the worker thread.

Minimal code example:

```
class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    error = pyqtSignal(tuple)
    result = pyqtSignal(object)
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)


class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        self.signals.result.emit(result)
        self.signals.finished.emit()

class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        self.displayButton.clicked.connect(self.displayFile)

    def loadFiles(self):
        fpaths, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, '')
        for fpath in fpaths:
            self.workerStarting("Load file")
            worker = Worker(load_files, fpath)
            worker.signals.result.connect(self.fileLoaded)
            self.threadpool.start(worker)

    def fileLoaded(self, file):
        """Add filename to the UI"""
        self.uiListFiles.addItem(file.name)

    def displayFile():
        self.figImage.clear()
        self.figImage.imshow(...)
        self.figCanvas.draw()
```

Comment: Something like http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#push_front ?

Comment: Well yes, except that I want to push it to the front of the queue in the QThreadPool, not to the front of a list

Comment: The only possibility for that appears to be priority parameter: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html#start Or, you can try to rearrange the queue with http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html#tryTake and `start()` again.

Comment: Thank you! That's much better and simpler than anything else I could fine. It doesn't give complete control, but at least it makes a big difference.